# Time Given Distance and Velocity Vectors

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, vectors

I recently came across a problem that gives velocity and two positions (which I solved for distance) in vector notations (). My question is, given the vectors for velocity and distance, how do I solve for time. If it had been given in numbers or variables, the problem would be much simpler; however, my only guess is this: (the distance) $<2914>= <-20x,-90y, 40z>$ (velocity vector). Once I solved for each variable, I took the magnitude of the resultant and got 166.082 seconds. This doesn't make any sense because I treated time as a vector quantity rather than a scalar (as it should be). Additionally, I do not think my operations were correct. I am not asking for the answer; rather, I hope someone can offer guidance or correct my thought process to approaching this problem.

Edit: I will write the question as it is given:

> A spaceship traveling at a given velocity <-30,-100,50> m/w is observed to be at a location <200,350,-500> m relative to an origin located on a nearby asteroid. At a later time, the ship is at location <-380,-2300, 600> m.
>
> (c) how long did it take for the ship to travel between these two locations?

Comment: Hi EMathS. It's hard to work out what you're asking. Could you edit your question and give more details of the calculation. If you make it clear you're interested in how to calculate time, rather than just want the answer, you should avoid the [homework black hole](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange).

Comment: The relationship between distance and velocity is different for different types of movement. If the movement is accelerated, $D = v^2/2a$, and if the movement is with constant velocity, $D = vt$. Both formulas are valid for a movement on a straight line. But from your text one cannot know this. So, tell us these things. Your notations are also unclear, what means <-20x, -90y, 40z>(velocity vector) ?

Comment: For D=vt, how would you divide a scalar quantity by a vector and get a scalar answer?